# Implementación de aplicación web .net en amazon web services

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services

el siguiente posteo lo realizo con el fin de obtener ayuda de alguien que sepa como realizar la implementaciones .net en amazon web services.

Bien, sucede los siguiente:
Realice una aplicación en aspx (vb.net) y la estoy intentando implementar en Amazon  Web Services, en un principio me aparecían los errores 400 y 403, lo cuales ya pude solucionar, al final pude subir la aplicación pero ahora me aparece el siguiente error

"500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

La vdd es que necesito que alguien me ayude a solucionar este problema o que me explique como es que se realiza la implementación en AWS, puesto que soy nuevo en esto y no tengo la mas minima idea...

Saludos.

Comment: Pero que tipo de servicio quieres consumir de aws? o lo usas como host?

Comment: Pues por lo poco que me explicaron estan usando Elastic Beanstalk, de hecho visual studio tiene una herramienta para publica desde ashi, pero aun asi me sale el mismo error, de vdd que ya no se que hacerle

Comment: El error 500 es muy generico tienes algo mas de informacion. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-getstarted.html supongo que ya leiste este tutorial.

Comment: De hecho lei ese tutorial, vi uno que ellos mismos publican, lei otros tanto y al final el resultado es el mismo, mi aplicacion en EBS ya esta en verde pero al momento de darl click al url me manda el error 500, no se que mas pueda ser...

Comment: puedes intentar publicar un sitio simple, talvez el error no sea en la publicacion sino en el paquete de publicacion(codigo)